# Sql queries that span multiple rows and substring them

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| id | caption         | offset |
|----|-----------------|--------|
| 1  | The quick fox   | 0      |
| 2  | jumped over the | 14     |
| 3  | lazy fox. The   | 30     |
| 4  | cow jumped over | 44     |
| 5  | the moon        | 52     |
```

The above table contains data that relates to a block of text that I want to search.

A query I'm running with elastic returns the offset of the entire block of text
concatenated together, for example:

```
{
  searchQuery: 'over the lazy fox.',
  beginning: 21,
  end: 34
}
```

The beginning and end must be checked via the offset; any that fall between those
two numbers should be included in the return data. To make things more tricky, I'd also like the matching portion of the text. It is important each of the rows are kept separate as there is extra row information omitted here.

```
| id | caption         | highlight |
|----|-----------------|-----------|
| 2  | jumped over the | over the  |
| 3  | lazy fox. The   | lazy fox. |
```

I'd also like to be able to highlight multiple searches at once, if an array of beginnings and ends were provided, return all matching rows and highlights.

Comment: can you explain a bit more the array-scenario? Also, I feel your example is incorrect since `end` is `34` then `highlight` only matches `lazy`.

Answer (score 0):

For one-search scenario,

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,IF(@beginning >= offset
                ,RIGHT(caption,len(caption)-(@beginning-offset))
                ,LEFT(caption,@end-offset)) as highlight
from @table
WHERE offset >= (select MAX(offset) from @table where offset <= @beginning)
    and offset <= @end
```

For array-search scenario,

```
SELECT 
t.*
,IIF(_beginning >= offset
            ,RIGHT(caption,len(caption)-(_beginning-offset))
            ,LEFT(caption,_end-offset)) as highlight
,a.id
from @table t
    join @array a ON offset >= (select MAX(offset) from @table where offset <= _beginning)
        and offset <= _end
order by a.id asc
```

insert the valuesto to be searched in the following table (variable) before running the second query,

```
declare @array as table(id int, _beginning int, _end int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for a single search query.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    caption,
    LEFT(RIGHT(caption, offset + LENGTH(caption) - @beginning), @end - offset) AS highlight
FROM some_table
WHERE offset + LENGTH(caption) >= @beginning 
AND offset <= @end;
```

Maybe resort to a [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) for combining multiple searches into one result set.

**N.B.** I did have modify your example with what I guess are the intended offsets, and set `@end` to 38, to get your expected result set.

```
+----+-----------------+--------+
| id | caption         | offset |
+----+-----------------+--------+
|  1 | The quick fox   |      0 |
|  2 | jumped over the |     14 |
|  3 | lazy fox. The   |     29 |
|  4 | cow jumped over |     42 |
|  5 | the moon        |     57 |
+----+-----------------+--------+
```